# How to delete table content from sqlite Django

Tags: python, django, database

[image]

I want to delete the data when pressing the trash bin button. I am able to submit, edit petty cash into the database. I am only left with deleting the data.

**This is my views.py**

```
def deleteclaims(request, id):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']

  #get id of particular form.
  claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)

  if request.method == 'POST':
      claims.name = request.POST['name']
      claims.email = request.POST['email']
      claims.claim = request.POST['claim']
      claims.claimtype = request.POST.get('claimtype')
      claims.description = request.POST['description']
      claims.receipt = request.FILES['receipt']
      claims.cheque = request.POST.get('Cheque')
      claims.status = request.POST['status']
      
      claims.delete()
      
      claims.save()
   return render(request, 'Login/existingclaims.html', {'claims':claims, 'user':user},  {'action' : 'Delete claims'})
```

**In my html**

```
<tr align="center">
              <td>{{ claims.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ claims.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ claims.email }}</td>
              <td>{{ claims.claim }}</td>
              <td>{{ claims.claimtype }}</td>
              <td>{{ claims.description }}</td>
              <td><a href="/media/{{ claims.receipt }}"> Click to View </a></td>
              <td>{{ claims.cheque }}</td>
              <td>{{ claims.status }}</td>
              <td><a href="/editclaims/{{claims.id}}"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a></td>
              <td><a href="/deleteclaims/{{claims.id}}"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: You're calling `save()` after `delete()` which is re-inserting the deleted record

Comment: remove everything other than ```claims.delete()```  from that if block

Comment: I've removed save() but Im having this error
TypeError: 'SaveClaimForm' object is not iterable

Comment: on which line..?

Comment: On the return render line

Comment: @EltonTan you should always return a redirect after a succesful POST request not render a template

Comment: Is it something like this? return redirect(request, 'Login/existingclaims.html', {'claims':claims, 'user':user})

Comment: The "claims" will no longer exist, you should redirect to some list/index view

Comment: @EltonTan did you solved this?

Comment: Yes, I have made changes, to create a variable called `results` to store the `SaveClaimForm` after deleting it.